# Embedded Images Causing Problems With imap_fetchbody()

Tags: php, imap

I have an email system that retrieves emails using PHP and then puts them in the database.

This works fine, however one issue is when an email has embedded images (not attachments) placed anywhere in the email body.

When my PHP script comes across this data it parses the whole mail as a load of rubbish for want of a better word, meaning I have no idea what was said in the email at all.

The problem comes with this part here:

```
$message        =   imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,1.2);
echo $message;
```

This comes out as something like the following:

> /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAoHBwgHBgoICAgLCgoLDhgQDg0NDh0VFhEYIx8lJCIf
>   IiEmKzcvJik0KSEiMEExNDk7Pj4+JS5ESUM8SDc9Pjv/2wBDAQoLCw4NDhwQEBw7KCIoOzs7Ozs7
>   Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozs7Ozv/wAARCAAxAI8DASIA
>   AhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQA
>   AAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3

Has anyone had this issue and managed to fix it or know how to?

I have tried the following functions but to no avail:

```
quoted_printable_decode( $message );  
imap_qprint( $message );
imap_utf8( $message );
```

Using `base64_decode( $message )` just prints it as below:

> ����JFIF``��C
>
> ## %$""!&+7/&)4)!"0A149;>>>%.DIC;��C
>
> ;("(;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;��1�"��
>   ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br�
>   %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz���������������������������������������������������������������������������
>   ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br�
>   $4�%�&'()*56789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������?�j(��r[�t�m9KO�G�p����[np
>   4i���%�cA՘�ƹx�����O�v$�*�B�o8 �Q���

Comment: That's base64 encoding...

Comment: see my updated with using base64_decode(), that hasn't helped its just put it in another un-readable format.

Comment: That's a jpeg,  write it out to disk and load it in. You can tell because of the JFIF header.

Comment: The trouble is that it garbles the WHOLE message which means I can't read any of the message body including text as it gets garbled by the embedded image...

Comment: Why do you assume part 1.2 is the text body? You need to examine the message structure (bodystructure) to figure out which part is text, which are images... etc. in this case, part 1.2 is an image.

Comment: Just `print_r()` the `imap_fetchstructure, I see some parts related to PLAIN and HTML, I also see the one for JPEG... How do I determine then which to pull in from this?

Comment: I just did `print_r()` on `imap_fetchstructure`, I see some parts related to PLAIN and HTML, I also see the one for JPEG... How do I determine then which number to pull as the part number to use from this?

Comment: Thanks for putting me in the right direction Max, I found a script that grabs the correct part and it's solved my issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was to do with grabbing the incorrect part of the email (the part referencing 1.2).

This was solved by using the amazing tool I found below and it has now solved my issue:

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-imap-message-body-attachments/

Thanks to Max for pointing out about the issue here.